# how to set back face color of a 3D square in Metalkit?

Tags: ios, metalkit

while using metalkit for an iOS application to draw a 3D square. I'd like the square to have different color on front face and back face. How do I do with this? any code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the color of anything is not "set", it's whatever is produced by your fragment shader. So, you would make your fragment shader produce a different color if the primitive is drawn back-facing. To determine that, use the `[[front_facing]]` attribute on a `bool` input parameter to your fragment shader and check that parameter's value in your shader logic.